# typescript "not a subtype of the indexer", what does it mean?

Tags: typescript

I am learning Typescript by reading [this official document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) about indexer type.

I can't understand this code:

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: string]: number;
    length: number;    // ok, length is a number
    name: string;      // error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
}
```

**First**, why do you put 'length' inside index type???

```
let myDict : NumberDictionary;
myDict[10] = 23;
```

NumberDictionary is an index type. Why there is a length in the NumberDictionary definition? Index type is supposed to be a[10], why there is length? Array object in javascript has length, but is index type an array? If so, why the above example defines a length? Is it necessary? 
Sorry for my rant. You can see I am very confused.

**Second,**

```
name: string;// error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
```

I don't understand the comment on this line. Why name must be subtype of the indexer? The indexer is like a[10] = "Tom", then what is the subtype of indexer?

Comment: The purpose of that code is to serve as a bad example. So, I suppose, 'ok' comment means only that it's ok from the type checker point of view, not that it makes sense in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand the comment on this line. Why name must be subtype of the indexer?

Because for any `string` access TypeScript will assume type `number` (based on `[index: string]: number;`). So if `name: string;` was allowed the following would assume `number` but really you might think *string*:

```
let x: NamedDictionary = Object.create(null);
let n = "name";
let y = x[n]; // TypeScript assumes `number`
let z = x["name"]; // Would you want `string`?
```

See the inconsistency between `y` and `z` ^

Comment: the property can be accessed by indexer syntax, a["name"] will return a number, not string defined by indexer type signature.

Answer (score 0):

to answer the first question, NumberDictionary is an object interface. It is not an array interface. Index signature refer to any index inside object.

A NumberDictionary object has two mandatory values `length` and `name`. It can has extra attributes, only if it matches the index signature (index and value type).

### Interface

```js
    interface NumberDictionary {
        [index: string]: number | string;
        length: number;
        name: string;
    }
    
    let nd: NumberDictionary = { length: 10, name: "Ten", lang: "en" };
```

### Index signature

```js
    [index: string]: number | string;
```

This means that i can set an extra `lang: string` to my object without type errors

If you know that `lang:string` has to be optional in my object, you have to set it in my interface

```js
    interface NumberDictionary {
        [index: string]: number | string;
        length: number;
        name: string;
        lang?: string;
    }
    
    let nd: NumberDictionary = { length: 10, name: "Ten", lang: "en" };
```