# TypeScript: Indexable type, string[] is not assignable

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org)'s has [Indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) which let us describe types we can index into. e.g. One can define an string array like this:

```
interface StringArray { 
  [key: number]: string;
}

let x: StringArray = ['Sheldon', 'Cooper'];
x[0] = 'John';
x[1] = 'Snow';
```

By looking at the index signature `[key: number]: string;` what I understand is, it defines the name of the key/index: `key` and the type of the key: `string`, and the type of the value which is returned i.e. `number`. Now when I change type of the key to string I get an error.

```
interface MyStringArray { 
  [key: string]: string;
}

//Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'MyStringArray'.
//Index signature is missing in type 'string[]'. 
var y: MyStringArray = ['Sheldon', 'Cooper']; //<- causes the error
y[0] = 'John';
y[1] = 'Snow';
```

I am not able to understand why it shows up the warning when I change key's type to `string`. Why it's not happening when `key` 's type is `numeric`. Is it because of array cause array indexes are numeric?

And **what happens when we have both indexed type and other properties**.

**Example 1:** It shows error with indexer type

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: string]: number;
    length: number;    // ok, length is a number
    name: string;      // error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
}
```

**Example 2:** It does not shows error when I change type of `[index:string]` to `[index: number]`

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: number]: number;
    length: number;    // ok, length is a number
    name: string;      // after chaning `index` type to number it's does'nt show error
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `[key: number]: string` defines the numeric key and the value as string (other way around then you described). And array of strings is indexed by numbers so it can be described with such a construct.

as to your interfaces consider one more:

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    [index: number]: number;
    prop: string;    // ok, irrelevant to indexer as prop is not a number
    '1': string;      // error - must return number
}
```

Only properties that meet the `key` requirement of being a number are validated against the index return type. This makes sense as you cannot access `prop` using `[]` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is because string[] uses numeric index. If you want to use index as a string then you need to change the code something like below.

```
interface StringArray {
    [index: string]: string;
}

let myArray: StringArray;
myArray["1"] = "Bob";
myArray["2"]="Fred";

let myStr: string = myArray[0];
```

**what happens when we have both indexed type and other properties.**

Well, As per the [Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types),

> There are two types of supported index signatures: string and number.

So example 1 is of type string index signature so they enforce all properties to match their return type.

> While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the
>   “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match
>   their return type. This is because a string index declares that
>   obj.property is also available as obj["property"].

When you changed it to number in example 2, it changed **NumberDictionary** to number index signature so it will allow the properties to have any return type.

Comment: what about this `what happens when we have both indexed type and other properties.`

Comment: explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599602/typescript-not-a-subtype-of-the-indexer-what-does-it-mean

Comment: Your link  doe not explain reason for this: `It does not shows error when I change type of [index:string] to [index: number]`

Comment: @AshishMulaye number dictionary will validate number properties of the object see my example

Comment: Yes. That is correct. However, if you use the string index signature, all the properties must also have type string which is not the case if you use number index signature. e.g. in your answer "prop" can be of type string, but if you use `[index: string]: number;` then "prop" will only allow string.